# Is there a command for switch to vicmd mode in zsh?

Tags: zsh, line-editor

I have mapped <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>k</kbd> and <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>j</kbd> for browsing history, but I would like to switch vicmd automatically whenever I call up a history entry, because most of the time I need to move the cursor to a certain position and make some changes.

Here is my current settings in .zshrc, what should I do to reach the goal mentioned above?

```
    bindkey '^[k' up-line-or-history
    bindkey '^[j' down-line-or-history
```

Answer (score 5):

What you want can be accomplished by just pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> after or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> but if you want to save that 1 keystroke, then adding the following to your `.zshrc` can help you.

```
vi-cmd-up-line-history() { 
  zle vi-cmd-mode
  zle up-line-or-history 
} 
zle -N vi-cmd-up-line-history 
bindkey -M vicmd '^[k' vi-cmd-up-line-history
bindkey -M viins '^[k' vi-cmd-up-line-history

vi-cmd-down-line-history() { 
  zle vi-cmd-mode
  zle down-line-or-history 
} 
zle -N vi-cmd-down-line-history
bindkey -M vicmd '^[j' vi-cmd-down-line-history
bindkey -M viins '^[j' vi-cmd-down-line-history
```

What it does is bind new widgets called `vi-cmd-down-line-history` and `vi-cmd-up-line-history` to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>. These widgets change the mode to *cmd* by calling the widget `vi-cmd-mode` and then fire the `down-line-or-history` and `up-line-or-history` respectively.

Comment: This doesn't work at all, when alt+k were pressed the first time, it turned up the most recent command, but then nothing happened in response to alt+k again.

Comment: How about adding `-M vicmd` like `bindkey -M vicmd '^[k' vi-cmd-up-line-history`

I added that as an edit, so try again. ;)